# Terraform Reference Created S3 Bucket for Remote Backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to setup a remote Terraform backend to S3. I was able to create the bucket, but I used bucket_prefix instead of bucket to define my bucket name. I did this to ensure code re-usability within my org.

My issue is that I've been having trouble referencing the new bucket in my Terraform back end config. I know that I can hard code the name of the bucket that I created, but I would like to reference the bucket similar to other resources in Terraform.

Would this be possible?

I've included my code below:

```
#configure terraform to use s3 as the backend
terraform {
   backend "s3" {
      bucket         = "aws_s3_bucket.my-bucket.id"
      key            = "terraform/terraform.tfstate"
      region         = "ca-central-1"    
   }
}
```

AWS S3 Resource definition

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-bucket" {
    bucket_prefix = var.bucket_prefix

    acl = var.acl

    lifecycle {
        prevent_destroy = true
    }

    versioning {
        enabled = var.versioning
    }

    server_side_encryption_configuration {
        rule {
            apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
               sse_algorithm = var.sse_algorithm
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A ready to use example is available here: https://github.com/aryounce/terraform-aws-bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Terraform needs a valid backend configuration when the initialization steps happens (`terraform init`), meaning that you have to have an existing bucket before being able to provision any resources (before the first `terraform apply`).

If you do a `terraform init` with a bucket name which does not exist, you get this error:

```
The referenced S3 bucket must have been previously created. If the S3 bucket
│ was created within the last minute, please wait for a minute or two and try
│ again.
```

This is self explanatory. It is not really possible to have the S3 bucket used for backend and also defined as a Terraform resource. While certainly you can use `terraform import` to import an existing bucket into the `state`, I would NOT recommend importing the backend bucket.

Comment: Thanks Ervin, I understand that I cannot reference the backend before the S3 bucket is created.

Instead I commented out the backend code block and applied the tf configuration. This created the bucket, but I was wondering if it would be possible to reference the bucket name using the "my-bucket.id" notation instead of hardcoding the bucket name.

Comment: Terraform validation will not allow to use variables there. It will raise this error: `Variables may not be used here.`

Comment: Got it, I will continue to use the hard coded bucket name. As someone new to Terraform, I was wondering if I was missing something.

Thanks for your help!